# Object is not being created with info from JSONP API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'm relatively new to jQuery and Javascript, I'm trying to create an object with information received from an API. The object is supposed to hold an object of basic info, for each of the users from the array `users`. To do so I make an API call for each user and then pass the json to a constructor that is supposed to create its properties. However, when I run the code the object only has a name property. And only for the first user, not all.

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/";

    var users = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
    
    var streamersObj = {};
    
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        console.log(users[i]);
        connectToApi(users[i]);
    }
        
    
    function StreamerObjCreate (jsonObj, name) {
       streamersObj[name] = name;
       streamersObj[name].onStream = jsonObj.stream;
       streamersObj[name].channel = jsonObj._links.channel;
       streamersObj[name].stream = jsonObj._links.self;
       console.log(streamersObj);    
    } 
  function connectToApi (target) {
      url = url + target + "?" + "callback=?";
    $.getJSON(url, function (json) {
        StreamerObjCreate(json, target);
    });
  } 
    console.log(streamersObj);
});
```

I just started to learn, so if you have any feedback related or unrelated it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Just a comment: $.getJSON function doesn't send a JSON to the callback function, so don't use "json" as variable name, it's confusing. It's more accurate to call it "data".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're overriding the url variable each time in your connectToApi function. Try this one instead

```
function connectToApi (target) {
    var targetUrl = url + target + "?" + "callback=?";
    $.getJSON(targetUrl, function (json) {
        StreamerObjCreate(json, target);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a string, and then assigning properties to that string. Try:

```
 function StreamerObjCreate (jsonObj, name) {
   streamersObj[name] = {
     name: jsonObj.name,
     onStream: jsonObj.stream,
     channel: jsonObj._links.channel,
     stream: jsonObj._links.self
   }
   console.log(streamersObj);    
}
```